# What is the performance impact of having many unused CSS selectors/rules?

Tags: css, performance

How much time/space does removing unused CSS selectors save? Is there a way for me to measure that on different web browsers?

Comment: Probably the browser won't notice it, but you will. Having well organized and documented files will save you much time and headaches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only real impact will come from the css file size being slightly larger, resulting in longer download and parse times.

But for the most part, there are a few million other things with much bigger impact.

Comment: Interesting topic. I have seen quite a few comments to the effect that the effect is negligible, but what do you think about Nick Confer's  comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292802/do-unused-css-styles-affect-load-times